# Asynchronous logging scope in .NET Core

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library

In .NETCore I want to support such scenario where I wrap code in some context like:

```
using(new LoggingContext("Method 1"))
{

}
```

Those contexts can also be embedded in one another

```
using(new LoggingContext("Method 1"))
{
   Method2();
}

void Method2() 
{
   using(new LoggingContext("Method 2"))
   {
      logger.Log("ERROR")
   }
}
```

After calling `logger.Log("ERROR")` I want it to log passed message along with those stacked contexts identifiers like:

> Method 1 > Method 2 > ERROR

It is very easy in single thread scenario - it requires a globally accessible stack of contexts. In .NET Core it is for example some `public static AsyncLocal<Stack<LoggingContext>>`.

However I don't know what is the best way to achieve similar behavior in multithreaded scenario like this:

```
using(LoggingContext("Method 1"))
{
    Task.WaitAll(
       new Task(() => Method("Method A", "A"), 
       new Task(() => Method("Method B", "B")))
}

void Method(string contextName, string message)
{
   using(new LoggingContext(contextName)
   {
       _logger.Log(message)
   }
}
```

The desired log would look like this:

> Method 1 > Method A > A 
>   Method 1 > Method B > B

Of course one task can start in another task and situation gets even more complicated.

**One more thing to note:**
For some legacy reasons it is impossible to pass dependency everywhere I create LoggingContext it must be some static solution.

The only idea I can think of is to use `ExecutionContext.SupressFlow` whenever I create a new Task and copy current stack to the new `AsyncLocal` object but is it a good solution? Messing with execution context seems a bit unsafe for me.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to manually clone or extend your parent logging context when you create a new task:

```
using(var parentContext = LoggingContext("Method 1"))
{
    Task.WaitAll(
       new Task(() => {
          using(parentContext.Clone()) 
          {
              Method("Method A", "A");
          }
       }), 
       ...
}
```

It's not pretty, but you could write some helper methods to handle the messy bits. For example:

```
using(var parentContext = LoggingContext("Method 1"))
{
    Task.WaitAll(
       parentContext.StartTask(() => Method("Method A", "A")),
       parentContext.StartTask(() => Method("Method B", "B")));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but as far as I understand your post it does not help with my problem. The problem is not how to copy the stack but how to store it separately for each task/context.

Comment: I don't know of a way to automatically cause your context to get cloned to each new task that you create. My proposed solution was just to store a new context *explicitly* for each task that you create. If that's not possible, then it's possible that there's something you can do with the TaskScheduler, but I don't know what that would look like.